# Is there any formats/token in ngx-quill similar to formats/token in quillJS editor?

Tags: angular, quill, ngx-quill

I am trying to implement template functionality using `ngx-quill(<quill-editor>)` similar to [quilljs](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1759).

I am not finding proper documentation to implement the same.

Can anyone help me to find?

Comment: read https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-quill

Comment: How to dynamically update the modules toolbar for ngx-quill editor?